# Some requests fails during autoscaling in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod, horizontal-scaling

I set up a k8s cluster on microk8s and I ported my application to it. I also added a horizontal auto-scaler which adds pods based on the cpu load. The auto-scaler works fine and it adds pods when there is load beyond the target and when I remove the load after some time it will kill the pods.

The problem is I noticed at the exact same moments that the auto-scaler is creating new pods some of the requests fail:

```
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  502
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://10.203.101.61/gateway/compile
POST Response Code :  502
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://10.203.101.61/gateway/compile
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  502
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://10.203.101.61/gateway/compile
POST Response Code :  502
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://10.203.101.61/gateway/compile
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Code :  200
```

I like to know what is the reason for this and how I can fix it?

Update:
I think it is better I give you more information regarding my set up:

The traffic is coming from outside of the cluster but both the k8s node and the program that generates the requests are on one machine so there is no network problem. There is a custom nginx component which doesn't do load balancing and just act as a reverse proxy and sends the traffic to respective services.

I ran another test which gave me more info. I ran the same benchmarking test but this time instead of sending the requests to the reverse proxy (nginx) I used the IP address of that specific service and I had no failed request while auto-scaler did its job and launched multiple pods. I am not sure if the problem is Nginx or k8s?

Comment: Have you put some readiness and liveness probe on your deployment? that traffic is internal or comes from external network through an ingress?

Comment: No, I don't have liveness probe. The traffic is coming from outside of the cluster but both the k8s node and the program that generates the requests are on one machine so there is no network problem. There is a custom nginx component which doesn't do load balancing and just act as a reverse proxy and sends the traffic to respective services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question:

> I am not sure if the problem is Nginx or k8s?

According to ingress-nginx docs:

> The NGINX ingress controller does not uses Services to route traffic
>   to the pods. Instead it uses the Endpoints API in order to bypass
>   kube-proxy to allow NGINX features like session affinity and custom
>   load balancing algorithms. It also removes some overhead, such as
>   conntrack entries for iptables DNAT

So I believe the problem is in Nginx, which does not make use of all Kubernetes features(e.g. kube-proxy) and is sending requests to Pods before they are completely ready.
However apparently this [problem](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3789) was [fixed](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/3628) in 0.23.0 (Feb/2019), so you should check your version.
Personally, I experience less issues after switching from Ingress-Nginx to [Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/about/why-ambassador), which by default forwards requests to Services (so Kubernetes is in charge of load balancing and sending it to the proper Pod).

Answer (score 4):

When the new pods are spawned, Kubernetes immediately starts to redirect traffic to them.
However, usually, it takes a bit of time for the pod to boot and become operational (ready).

To prevent this from happening, you can define a [Readiness Probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes) for your pods.
K8s will periodically call the pod on the readiness endpoint that you have provided, to determine if this pod is functional and ready to accept requests.
K8s won't redirect traffic to the pod until the readiness endpoints returns a successful result depending on the [type of probe](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-setting-up-health-checks-with-readiness-and-liveness-probes) (check "*Types of Probes*" section).

Comment: Thank you for your answer meanwhile, I ran another test which gave me more info. I ran the same benchmarking test but this time instead of sending the requests to the reverse proxy (nginx) I used the IP address of that specific service and I had no failed request while auto-scaler did its job and launched multiple pods. I am not sure if the problem is Nginx or k8s?

Comment: I have faced the similar issue, scale your Core/kube DNS deployment. There is a limitation on DNS query per second in core/kube DNS, So when a new pod spins up it will put more load on DNS server and you starts getting 502.

Comment: My problem was not related to k8s but as @VictorVal said it is an issue with Nginx and I solved it by adding a readiness probe to my deployment. Now the Nginx sends traffic to newly created pods just when they are ready.